# How to utilize Yolo on high resolution images 8k

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo

I have recently started working in this field. And currently the requirement is to train Yolov3 on a custom dataset where images are of 8k resolution. Is there a straight forward pipeline that I can utilize?. Or is there a way to run inference on 8k images ? with a yolo trained on 416x416 images ?.

So far have read couple of papers and found github repos but none of them are straight forward.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question by any chance?

Comment: Sorry no reply so far :(. I am trying sliding window but its incredibly slow

Comment: You can try to reduce overlap of sliding window, e.g. 1/3 or 1/2 overlap. Add to it a prior down scaling of your 8K image, if needed, to make the object you are detecting fit into the window.